# inline block and middle text?

Tags: html, css

I've made this code for navigation bar.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="header-nav">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="../Pictures/LifeFrame/2.jpg" width="100%" height="100px" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav" align="center">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.header-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.nav {
    height: 42px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:42px;
    float:left;
}
```

but the text in tag a is on top not in middle. how to make the text in a tag with display inline block to middle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to center "Home" in the block you've created?

Try in css with padding.

```
a{
   display:inline-block;
   width:50%;
   height:42px;
   float:left;
   padding-top: 2px;
```

}

Play with that

Comment: really thanks i must used padding even it must change the height also but finally it center >.< thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `float` rule `vertical-align` may not work in this case so You can provide margins to this like following:

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:42px;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 0; /* add this */
}
```

OR

If you want to use `vertical-align` then you need to adjust width accordingly

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%; /* reduce width */
    height:42px;
    /*float:left; */ /* remove this */
    margin: 10px 0; /* add this */
    vertical-align:middle;/* add this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/do23ez55/)

### [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/do23ez55/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `vertical-align: middle;`

More info. on vertical-align: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

Remove float and use vertical-align:

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:42px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this: 
1) Keep your HTML as is.

2) Change your CSS as follows:

```
.header-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.nav {
    height: 42px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    vertical-align:50%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center
}
a {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqhewpo2/1/)

Comment: i ve never used `display:flex` before, just read about it. In the fiddle i am not able to see the nav text at all. Can you please correct it so that i can understand the `flex` property. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving `padding` for the `<a>` tag

**CSS:**

```
a{
    padding:10px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:42px;
    float:left;
}
```

See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpfsyds2/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your 'a' style:

```
    line-height: 42px;
```